# Convert ieee754 to decimal in node

Tags: node.js, npm, buffer, ieee-754

I have a buffer in node `<Buffer 42 d9 00 00>` that is supposed to represent the decimal 108.5.  I am using this module to try and decode the buffer: https://github.com/feross/ieee754.

```
ieee754.read = function (buffer, offset, isLE, mLen, nBytes)
```

The arguments mean the following:

```
buffer = the buffer
offset = offset into the buffer
value = value to set (only for write)
isLe = is little endian?
mLen = mantissa length
nBytes = number of bytes
```

I try to read the value: `ieee754.read(buffer, 0, false, 5832704, 4)` but am not getting the expected result.  I think I am calling the function correctly, although I am unsure about the `mLen` argument.

Answer (score 2):

[I discovered that] the node Buffer class has that ability built in: `buffer.readFloatBE(0)`.