# How to convert hex bit pattern (as string) to float in Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Let's say I have a hex value as a string:

```
var hexValue = "0x43480000";
```

How can I parse it in Node.js and convert it to a number (float)?
Like:

```
var parsedNumber = hexStringToNumber(hexValue); // -> 200.0
```

Note that the hex value is meant to be a **bit pattern** for an IEEE-754 floating-point number. So the result is 200, not 1128792064 as it would be with just `parseInt("0x43480000")`.

Answer (score 2):

*(The below obsoleted by the clarification by the OP.)*

<s>`parseInt` ([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) | [spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-parseint-string-radix)) is perfectly happy to parse hex in that format for you:</s>

```js
var hexValue = parseInt("0x43480000");
console.log(hexValue);
```

It will see the `0x` at the beginning and assume hex. If you had a string in hex without the prefix (`"43480000"`), you'd use `parseInt(str, 16)` to tell `parseInt` to use base 16 (hex). But since you have the prefix, there's no need.

The result will be a JavaScript number, which [by definition](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-terms-and-definitions-number-value) is a "double" (IEEE-754 double-precision binary floating point).

---

You've said you want `0x43480000` to come out as 200.0. That means you're not really parsing *hex*, you're trying to take a string containing the bit pattern of an IEEE-754 floating-point number, expressed as hex, and get the equivalent IEEE-754 floating-point number. That's very different from "parsing hex."

The [calculator](http://www.h-schmidt.net/FloatConverter/IEEE754.html) you referred to works with IEEE-754 **single**-precision binary floating point values. The 0x43480000 bit pattern isn't 200 in **double**-precision binary floating point. But 0x40690000 is.

The only *easy* way I know of to do that is with `DataView`:

```js
var dv = new DataView(new ArrayBuffer(8));
dv.setUint32(0, parseInt("0x40690000"));
var num = dv.getFloat64(0)
console.log(num);
```

If you want to convert the *single* precision version (0x43480000), I don't think there's anything built-in that's going to do it for you. You'll have to isolate the mantissa and exponent bits, do the widening, and then do the above.

Comment: But that doesn't make it a float or double.

Comment: @HarmjanKors: Yes it does. All numbers in JavaScript are doubles (IEEE-754 double-precision binary floating point). I would have said, but I thought you knew that from the way you phrased your question. :-)

Comment: Yes I know :) But `parseInt("0x43480000")` results in `1128792064`, but I would like to receive value `200.0` (like this converter for example: http://www.h-schmidt.net/FloatConverter/IEEE754.html).

Comment: @HarmjanKors: That calculator works with IEEE-754 **single**-precision binary floating point values. That bit pattern isn't 200 in **double**-precision binary floating point, but 0x40690000 is. I've added an example of converting that in the above.

Answer (score 2):

The Node.js [Buffer](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/buffer.html) class provides this feature:

```
var buf = new Buffer("43480000", "hex");
var number = buf.readFloatBE(0);
console.log(number); // 200
```

Also see:

- [Convert ieee754 to decimal in node](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28538749/convert-ieee754-to-decimal-in-node)
- [Encoding and decoding IEEE 754 floats in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3740853/encoding-and-decoding-ieee-754-floats-in-javascript)

Comment: Nicely done, but really what you've done is establish that this question is a duplicate of your first link. You can't comment yet (you will be able to soon at >= 50 rep), but when you can the thing to do is to post a link to the original question as a comment on the duplicate.